# AngularUI $StateParams multiple parameters coming back undefined

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

Simply trying to get the token sent back to me in URL. New to AngularUI so not understanding why.

Here is the route:

```js
angular.module('myApp')
  .config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('oauth_callback', {
        url: '/oauth_callback?access_token&expires_in',
        templateUrl: 'app/oauth_callback/oauth_callback.html',
        controller: 'OauthCallbackCtrl'
      });
  });
```

Here is all i'm doing for the controller:

```js
ngular.module('myApp')
  .controller('OauthCallbackCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
   console.log('## params:', $stateParams);
  });
```

The console log returns:

```
## params: Object {access_token: undefined, expires_in: undefined}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: if I use this syntax "url: "/oauth_callback/:access_token/:expires_in" it pushes me back to my .otherwise() route and controller is never initiated.

Comment: are you sure your url is `oauth_callback?access_token=xxxxx&expires_in=123` this format..then only the state paremes will populate in `$stateParams` object

Comment: the url request looks like this:

    localhost:9000/oauth_callback#access_token=60dfb35a-e8b4&expires_in=1209583

Comment: you url should be `http://localhost:9000/#/oauth_callback?access_token=60dfb35a-e8b4&expires_in=1209583` then your issue would be fixed..

Comment: Yes,it's the # between oauth_callback and the parameter.

But this URL is generated from THEIR site and I can't change the way it puts in the parameters.

Comment: but as per you current url should be the same as I mentioned..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've was into a similar issue when I was developing one app that uses `oAuth`, with `ui-router`.

My problem was a bit different, because some internal redirections that I do, to setup a i18n routing. When the `oAuth` was redirecting me back to my app, it was going crazy, because of the hash that it applies and the `ui-router` structure that I've developed.

I've ended up setting up the redirect URL on `oAuth` pointing to a neutral HTML page, that parses the hash, stores it on `localStorage`, and then I close the window.

When the user call the authentication, I trigger a new window/tab opening, with the oAuth server. On my angular app, I activate one `$interval` that looks for the existence and validity of the `localStorage` key defined by me. While its not filled up by that HTML, it keeps looking for it. When it gets it, I proceed with the things on the app.